# In Linux, how do I truncate command-line output?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

If I `grep -nr sumthin *` in my source code directory, it also spews out very long lines from minified JavaScript or CSS files.  I want to get just the first 80 characters per line.

For example, a regular `grep` gives me this:

```
css/style.css:21:   behavior: url("css/iepngfix.htc")
css/style-min.css:4:.arrow1{cursor:pointer;position:absolute;left:5px;bottom:10px;z-index:13;}.arrow2{cursor:pointer;position:absolute;right:5px;bottom:10px;z-index:13;}.calendarModule{z-index:100;}.calendarFooterContainer{height:25px;text-align:center;width:100%!important;z-index:15;position:relative;font-size:15px!important;padding:-2px 0 3px 0;clear:both!important;border-left:1px solid #CCC;border-right:1px  ... etc.
```

but I'd like to get just this instead:

```
css/style.css:21:   behavior: url("css/iepngfix.htc")
css/style-min.css:4:.arrow1{cursor:pointer;position:absolute;left:5px;bottom:
```

What Linux command can do this?

Comment: "minified"? What does that mean?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_(programming)

Comment: Thanks. Correct link is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_%28programming%29

Comment: Both links lead to the same page for me.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

OMG, I totally forgot about `cut`!

```
grep -nr sumthin * | cut -c -80
```

^ does the trick! >_<

Comment: That doesn't work if escape sequences or color codes are involved; take for example `git log --oneline --graph --color=always | cut -c -$COLUMNS`

Comment: I get that it doesn't truncate at exactly 80 displayed characters, but it still solves my problem:  none of the lines wrap, so you still only see the leading portion of each line (which is important in my specific use case, so I can see the `<file>:<linenumber>` output of `grep -n`).

Comment: Long commit comments also kinda "break" your sample command's output, if not truncated. `git log --oneline --graph --color=always | more` will show the graph interrupted by wrapped text. http://i.imgur.com/X8G7SIV.png

Comment: yeah, that's why I googled for this question to begin with :)

Comment: How would you truncate to the width of your terminal, without having to actually specify the number?

Comment: @Totor You can do something like `tail | less`, as per http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/20507/14925

Comment: @Totor `$(tput cols)`

Comment: @Ves nice, but apparently [non standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tput.html)

Comment: If the purpose is just to be able to visually see things well(not redirecting the output somewhere for use) then `less -S` is what you want. `-S` is `--chop-long-lines`. Basically, it turns off line wrapping

Answer (score 5):

Other than `cut` you can use `fold` (and in some cases `fmt`).
`fold` is part of `coreutils` package.

```
$ echo "some very long long long text" | fold -w 5   # fold on 5 chars per line
some 
very 
long 
long 
long 
text
```

`fold` doesn't *cut* the remaining text, but outputs it on the next line.

Comment: Thanks for this, this might be useful in the future.  In my case, I really wanted to cut the text, so the `file:linenumber` prefix of the `grep` output are contiguous, for easy scanning by eye.

Answer (score 1):

While not exactly what you want to do, you could use `awk` to print a certain number of columns.  You can specify the delimiter to be ":" in this case.

Comment: There isn't a specific delimiter, though.  I'm really cutting the output at a specific length, to make it fit in 1 line in the terminal.

Comment: @Nikki then cut is what you want.  I am sure that you can do something clever with awk to get the same thing but really, cut is easier.  ^_-